# LibreOffice pivot: How to count 1 per line?

Tags: pivot-table, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I have a list of fruit occurrences like this:

```
banana
banana
apple
orange
apple
```

And I want LibreOffice to give me a number of occurrences per fruit, for instance:

```
banana | 2
apple  | 2
orange | 1
```

How can I do this?

I guess that a pivot table would to require a column full of "1", and it is a pain to create this column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are (at least) two solutions:

1. Using a **pivot table**;
2. Using the **COUNTIF function** together with a list of distinct values.

### 1. Pivot table

The following pivot table layout...

[image]

will give you the following output:

[image]

### 2. COUNTIF and distinct values

Another approach involves the **[`COUNTIF` function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_COUNTIF_function)**. You can create the "result table" in two simple steps:

1. [Create a list of distinct values](http://openoffice.blogs.com/openoffice/2008/05/copying-only-th.html) (fruit names) using a standard filter:

   [image: Create list of distinct values]
2. Apply the countif function to all of the resulting distinct values like this:

   `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6;A9)`

   [image]